# How to add an empty line if grep reports multiple instances of the same pattern?

Tags: bash, grep

Ubuntu 16.04
Bash 4.4.0

I am using `grep` to search for the word 'error' in a json file which is a logfile. How can an empty line be added after each instance?

my command: `grep error "${wDir}"/"${client}"/logs/server.json >> "$eLog"`

the output:

```
{"name":"XXX_XXX","hostname":"xxx.xx.xxx","pid":5193,"level":30,"fbresponse":{"error":{"message":"(#200) User does not ....."}}}
{"name":"XXX_XXX","hostname":"xxx.xx.xxx","pid":5193,"level":30,"fbresponseraw":{"error":{"message":"(#200) User does not ..."}}}
{"name":"XXX_XXX","hostname":"xxx.xx.xxx","pid":5193,"level":30,"fbresponse":{"error":{"message":"(#200) User does not ....."}}}
{"name":"XXX_XXX","hostname":"xxx.xx.xxx","pid":5193,"level":30,"fbresponseraw":{"error":{"message":"(#200) User does not ..."}}}
```

The desired output:

```
{"name":"XXX_XXX","hostname":"xxx.xx.xxx","pid":5193,"level":30,"fbresponse":{"error":{"message":"(#200) User does not ....."}}}

{"name":"XXX_XXX","hostname":"xxx.xx.xxx","pid":5193,"level":30,"fbresponseraw":{"error":{"message":"(#200) User does not ..."}}}

{"name":"XXX_XXX","hostname":"xxx.xx.xxx","pid":5193,"level":30,"fbresponse":{"error":{"message":"(#200) User does not ....."}}}

{"name":"XXX_XXX","hostname":"xxx.xx.xxx","pid":5193,"level":30,"fbresponseraw":{"error":{"message":"(#200) User does not ..."}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `awk` for search and insert an empty line:

```
awk '/error/ { print $0 ORS }' "${wDir}"/"${client}"/logs/server.json
```

By default `ORS` (output record separator) is `\n`.

Comment: It does but I see the verbose in shell and I rather not.

Comment: This line shows the entire log in my shell as awk is scanning it ```awk '/error/ { print $0 ORS }' "${wDir}"/"${client}"/logs/server.json >> "$eLog" ```

Comment: No, it will only print lines if search word `error` is found anywhere in it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple is good.

```
sed '/error/G' "${wDir}"/"${client}"/logs/server.json >> "$eLog"
```

or if you want it to be case-insensitive

```
sed '/error/IG' "${wDir}"/"${client}"/logs/server.json >> "$eLog"
```

> examples:

```
$: cat x
a
error
b
c
foo error other stuff
d
e
foo other stuff ERROR ERROR
f
g

$: sed '/error/G' x
a
error

b
c
foo error other stuff

d
e
foo other stuff ERROR ERROR
f
g

$: sed '/error/IG' x
a
error

b
c
foo error other stuff

d
e
foo other stuff ERROR ERROR

f
g
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`:

```
grep "aa" a.txt | xargs printf "%s\n\n"
```

output:

```
aa

aa

aa

aa
```